# About the ordering of the questions in "featured" tab

Tags: feature-request

In the moment, the questions in the "featured" tab are ordered as a FIFO queue. This way, the questions whose bounty is ending sooner goes first in order to get more attention in the last moment.

But when there are more than one page of featured questions, the questions from the second and more pages will get much less attention than corresponds to their place in the queue.

This way, the questions get real attention only at the last day of their bounty (estimation based on the current count on stackoverflow). And this way, the 7 day period of the bounty reward is effectively reduced to 1 day or even less.

So, my suggestion is when the number of the featured questions is more than one page, the order to be based on random numbers. This way, the visitors attention will be distributed more evenly in the 7 days period and the chances to get useful answer will raise for all questions in the queue. IMHO, this will be win-win deal for all questions in the queue.

Comment: It is true, that page right now is a pretty bad mix of questions that are either very difficult/vague or are already answered but the OP is fishing for more.  Very few SO users make it to the paginated view.  Your proposal has merit but is going to generate a *lot* of complaints.  That always makes it a hard sell.  I recommend you ask for the lesser change, instead of the single page just make the paginated view the default so an SO user is more likely to make it to page 2.  Only gritty detail is how the tag preferences should be applied.  Tricky.

Comment: Well, I am not sure there will be complaints. At least for me is obvious that this way, the questions with bounty will have wider auditory (notice, that the view count will be approximately the same, but more evenly distributed in time).

Comment: I'd like the new ones to pop up at the top of the list. But not always (per bounty size, ...). Even if FIFO should be kept as default landing  ordering, users should then have the possibility to select and switch between different ordering options.